# How do I form a Github API POST request to add a new comment to a gist?

Tags: ruby, github

I'm doing a Post request to github at this url:

`https://api.github.com/gists/2710948/comments`

Theoretically, this should create a comment with the text being formed from what's in the request body. However, when I try to make that post, I get a 404 error. That leads me to believe that the gist is not being found, however, if you do a Get request at the same address it comes up just fine.

Is there an authentication thing I need to be doing? I've tried adding a username and password to my headers collection but I've got no idea if I'm using the right format. I've tried making this work via Ruby, HTTP Client, and curl, and I get the same error either way.

The curl command I'm using is this:

`curl -X POST -d "This is my sample comment" https://api.github.com/gists/2710948/comments`

I think that if I can get the curl command working, I'll be able to figure out the HTTP Client and then the Ruby. This will be my first attempt at consuming an API, so there's nothing too basic for me to double-check; all suggestions will be helpful.

Comment: this probably belongs here: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/, but stackoverflow won't let me flag it as such.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
curl -d '{ "body": "Test comment" }' -u "Username:Pass" -X POST https://api.github.com/gists/2710948/comments
```

Ruby code:

```
require 'net/http'

uri = URI("https://api.github.com/gists/2710948/comments")
req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.to_s)
req.basic_auth("Username", "Pass")
req.body = '{"body": "Test message"}'  # `to_json` can be used
req["content-type"] = "application/json"
Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port, :use_ssl => true) do |http|
  p response = http.request(req)
end
```

See also http://developer.github.com/v3/gists/comments/

Comment: This did the trick, alright. I'm a little confused as to what the basic_auth key is setting - is that a special field, like body is? Or is that setting some parameter somewhere else?

Comment: `basic_auth` adds `Authorization` header to the request: `Authorization: Basic VXNlcm5hbWU6UGFzcw==`    


`req.body` sets POST request body. In this case the data must be in JSON format and contain `body` key (comment text)